# How to change fontsize with pygame_gui?

Tags: python, pygame-gui

New to this package, unsure how to change a labe like this:

Want to make the font size larger...

```
problem_label = pygame_gui.elements.UILabel(
    relative_rect=pygame.Rect((300, 100), (200, 80)),
    text= generate_problem(),
    manager=manager,
)
```

Tried some online stuff, documentation wasn't helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.